# Не работает WebSocket

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket

Пытаюсь сделать минимальный рабочий пример с веб-сокетами. На стороне сервера использую `Spring Framework`, клиент - `JavaScript`.

- **Сервер**

К простому `Spring Boot` проекту добавил класс с конфигурацией:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(notificationWebSocketHandler(), "/notification").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public NotificationWebSocketHandler notificationWebSocketHandler() {
        return new NotificationWebSocketHandler();
    }
}

public class NotificationWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
            TextMessage message = new TextMessage("Notification " + i);
            session.sendMessage(message);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred");
                session.close(CloseStatus.SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }
        session.close(CloseStatus.NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connection closed with the status: " + status);
    }
}
```

- **Клиент** `index.html`

  ```
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="stomp.min.js"></script> -->
      <script>
          var url = 'http://localhost:8080/notification';
          var socket = new SockJS(url);

          socket.onopen = function() {
              console.log('Opening...');
          };

          socket.onclose = function() {
              console.log('Closing...');
          };

          socket.onmessage = function (event) {
              console.log('Received notification: ', event.data);
          }
      </script>
  </head>

  <body></body>
  ```

При открытии файла `index.html` в консоли браузера выходят ошибки:

> GET http://localhost:8080/notification/info?t=1554898230939 404
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/notification/info?t=1554898230939' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в документации по спрингу прочитал, что `.setAllowedOrigins("*")` позволяет делать запрос с любого домена. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev или это `XMLHttpRequest` не позволяет сделать запрос на другой домен. порт?

Comment: @notaProgrammer, попробуйте такое добавить(Kotlin): `@Configuration
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:4200",
                        "http://localhost:80"
                )
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
    }
}`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, проблема с `CORS` пропала. Но теперь получаю 404 по адресу "http://localhost:8080/notification/info?t=1554961148178". Не могу понять почему добавляется  "/info?t=1554961148178", ведь я пытаюсь подключить сокет по адресу "http://localhost:8080/notification"?

Comment: @notaProgrammer, тут, думаю, дело в либе на JS, возможно стоит другую попробовать или для этой документацию почитать. Возможно она ожидает определённого протокола, реализованного на сервере.